# My domain name wont work locally but works externally

Tags: router, dns, ip, port-forwarding

I have home server ip 192.168.1.10 and domain name eg example.com which is from namecheap. i did pointed to my Dynamic Ip have have ddclient that update my ip to namecheap A records . also i have my router forwarded all traffic from ports 80, 22, 8080 to my local server ip 192.168.1.10. everything works perfect except if i try to access my domain name eg example.com in my internal network i get "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" . if i use my local server ip 192.168.1.10 works fine, also if i use my dynamic public ip which is like 45.x.x.x it works fine. i can access my website eg example.com form external network but not internal. can anyone tell me where i am doing wrong? this is for educational purpose server at home.

Comment: Your key here is "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED", this is a DNS issue. What is your DNS server when you are in your local network? Please state specific OS and show output of `ipconfig /all` if Windows  or contents of /etc/resolv.conf if in Linux

Comment: server is linux , but i am trying to access my website from Win10 locally... MY dns server is 192.168.1.1 when i do ipconfig/all

Comment: So on your Windows 10 machine, what is the output of `nslookup example.com` except with your website name, and is it different than `nslookup example.com 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: C:\Users\Mini-pc>nslookup example.com
Server:  ControlPanel.Home
Address:  192.168.1.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to ControlPanel.Home timed-out

Comment: when i do (example is replace my domian name) nslookup exmaple.com 8.8.8.8 C:\Users\Mini-pc>nslookup example.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    EXAMPLE.COM
Address:  45.x.x.x

Comment: So your problem is with whatever 192.168.1.1 is... that nameserver is not responding properly to the request. What is that piece of equipment, a router, server, or ???

Comment: correct only when 192.168.1.1 not responding.. i am using router

Comment: is the result the same if you do `nslookup google.com` or does that work properly?

Comment: This is what i get ......C:\Users\Mini-pc>nslookup google.com
Server:  ControlPanel.Home
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4009:80a::200e
          216.58.216.78

Comment: OK, I think I understand what is happening. I will give you an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router at 192.168.1.1 is likely just a relay agent, and is passing the DNS request for your website up to (most likely) your ISP's DNS servers, which do not respond to the request for some reason (I really can't say why) thus you are not getting back an IP address for your PC to talk to (computers talk to IP addresses, not names directly).

The fix for this would be to change your DNS servers in your router, to something like [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) or [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/) (scroll to bottom of page for addresses to use) instead of using the ones provided in DHCP by your ISP. For whatever reason, your ISP's DNS servers are not responding to the request to resolve your namelookup request. The exact way to implement this could very based on your specific router and configuration.

As an alternative you could make a manual entry in your hosts file to point your website name to the public IP address manually, but this may not be a good answer if your IP address changes often.

Comment: Sorry if it isn't the answer you were looking for, but it is pretty straight-forward from the tests you did. My main concern would be your neighbors, or anyone else on that ISP, would get a similar response, and thus not be able to access your website.

Comment: the problem is fixed after changing my ISP dns to google DNS. thnks this is the correct answer